# How to display select options from an API in react JS?

Tags: json, reactjs, api, react-select, react-state

I am fairly new to react JS and I am trying to display options in a dropdown by hitting an API. I also tried doing it without states and that did not work either. So here is the code,

```
import React from 'react';
import './Search.css';

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
state={
filtered :[],
options :[],
}

async copyOptionsForAsync() {
  let response = await fetch("/category/all");
  let data = await response.json();

  data.forEach(element => {
    let dropDownEle = { label: element["title"], value: element };
    this.options.push(dropDownEle);
  });
  // this.setState({options})
  // console.log(this.state.options)
}

async handleSubmit(event){
      event.preventDefault();
try{
const url ='/jobs/all/'
const Response = await fetch((url),{
    method: `GET`,
    mode: 'cors',
        headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }});

const filtered = [];

const res = await Response.json();
const Location = this.refs.location.value;
const Category = this.refs.category.value; 

Object.keys( res ).forEach( function( key ) {
    if( res[key].location === Location && res[key].category === Category ) {
        filtered[key] = res[key];}
});
this.setState({filtered})
console.log(this.state.filtered)
        }
 catch (err) {
    console.error('err', err);}
    };
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
        <form action="/search" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <select ref="category" defaultValue="" onChange={this.copyOptionsForAsync} options={this.options}>
            {/* <option value="" defaultValue>Category</option>
            <option value="Ios Developer">Ios Developer</option>
            <option value="Java Developer">Java Developer</option>
            <option value="Marketing">Marketing Generalist</option>
            <option value="Web Developer">Web Developer</option>
            <option value="Python Developer">Python Developer</option>
            <option value="C# Developer">C# Developer</option> */}

          </select>
          <select ref="location">
            <option value="" defaultValue>Location</option>
            <option value="Lucknow">Lucknow</option>
            <option value="Ranchi">Ranchi</option>
            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
          </select>
          <button>Find</button>
        </form>
        {this.state.filtered.map((data)=>{
          //  return <div>{data.location}</div>  // you can render here list items
          return (
          <div className="flex-container">
          <div key={data.id}>
          <div>Job Title: {data.category}</div>
          <div>Location: {data.location}</div>
          <div>Position: {data.position}</div>
          <div>Duration: {data.duration}</div>
          <div>Skills Required: {data.skills_req}</div>
          <div>Apply By: {data.apply_by}</div>
          <div>Starting Date: {data.starting_date}</div>
          <div>Stipend: {data.stipend}</div>
          <div>About Work: {data.about_work}</div>
          <div>Perks: {data.perks}</div>
          </div>
          </div>)
        })}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default SearchForm;
```

By doing so, I am not able to display. Can I modify this code or should I go with a different approach? Please help me.

Comment: You've your options in state so you cannot directly set this.options.push(). This is wrong. So all you need it then() block. Instead of async and await use then block and then do this.setState({options: drowpDownEle}) and then you'll be able to display the options

Comment: I am not familiar with then block :/ @Mohit

Comment: What if when you iterate over your data by creating a new array locally and then do this.setState({options: temporaryOptionsArray}) ?